# Azure DevOps TFS Repos: link to internal file inside markup

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, azure-repos

We have a TFS repository on DevOps with a documentation folder.

The documentation is made using markdown syntax (in `.md` files).

We have inserted the link between different documents following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/contribute/how-to-write-links) and all works fine up to some days ago.

Right now, we're no more able to navigate between files in the Repos link, because the "path" parameter looks like this:

```
?path=%2F%24%2FDocs%2FHowTo%2FHome.md&version=T
```

decoding it:

```
?path=/$/Docs/HowTo/Home.md&version=T
```

The problem is the first `/`, if I manually remove it from the link, it works.

We have tried with all the following syntax, but the links keeps broken:

```
[Home](./Home.md)
[Home](Home.md)
[Home](/Home.md)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Repo Path URL, the `Home.md` file is under the `Howto Folder`.

You could try to use the `Absolute path` or `Relative path`.

For example:

Absolute path: `[Home]($/Docs/Howto/Home.md)`

Relative path: `[Home](./Howto/Home.md)`

Note: If you use the file path for navigation, the `.md` file and `home.md` file need to be in the **same** repo.

[image: Folder Path]

Here is the doc about the [markdown links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#links).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your reply and sorry for my late reply (email notification has been marked as spam).
Using the absolute path, the links are working, but we have more thank 4k links in our documentation and it's not so fun to replace all of them with the absolute path... Is there another way?
Thank you

Comment: Hi @KingOss. I can't find a simple enough way. If you need to use Relative path, you also need to point to the target folder path. For exampe: path `$/docs->A->B->C->Home.md`. Relative path: `/A/B/C/Home.md`.It seems that only the root node can be omitted.

Comment: On the other hand, you may directly use the Path URL. For example: `[Home](https://dev.azure.com/org/testdocs/_versionControl?path=%24%2Ftestdocs%2FA%2FB%2FC%2FD%2FHome.md&version=T&_a=preview)` . You could directly get the `FULL` URL path in ·Browser path bar· You could open `New TFVC pages` in Preview features.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin-Lu-MSFT, then I will evaluate to implement some automatic tool to automatically convert from relative to absolute path.